# php/laravel Работа с объемными csv

Tags: php, csv, данные

Кратко о стоящей задаче - обновлять данные в бд из csv файла. Периодически (условно раз в 1ч) прилетают новые csv файлы.

- Файлы объемные, порядка 800 000+ строк каждый
- Данные не отсортированы
- В новом файле обновлены только 5-10% данных, остальное это повторы

Если напрямую обрабатывать каждый файл(все данные перезаписывать в бд) - будет либо большая нагрузка, либо файл не успеет отработать до следующего прилетевшего.
Соответственно встает вопрос - как выцепить эти 5-10% обновленных значений и соответственно уже с ними дальше работать.
Пример данных в файле:

```
4;203762;193;153,4
4;203762;192;142,5
4;203765;193;186
```

Первая цифра\код одна из ключевых. Таких кодов около 30.
Мы можем либо

1. Сравнивать между собой файлы
2. Сравнивать последний файл с бд

Первый вариант я вижу таким:
Обходим весь файл, в процессе создаем около 30 файлов с отсортированными данными (читаем по 1000 строк, сортируем данные, через цикл открываем один из 30 файлов, записываем данные, закрываем файл, читаем след 1000 строк...). Делаем так для обоих файлов (старый и новый).
Далее открываем условный 1х новый файл. Считываем у него 250 строк, открываем старый 1хy файл, считываем в нем 250 строк. Сравниваем данные через **array_diff_assoc()** результат записываем в новый общий файл. Так проходим весь старый файл, считываем след 250 строк нового 1х файла и снова проходим весь 1хy старый файл.
В итоге получим файл, в котором только новые данные.

Второй вариант - так же разбиваем новый файл на 30 отсортированных частей. Но в процессе считывания частей файл - делаем запросы к бд на получение данных по 250 записей. Что-то похожее на это(если брать образец данных выше):

```
...where aaa=4 and bbb in (203762, 203765...)
```

Я больше склоняюсь к первому варианту, все же в приоритете снизить нагрузку для бд. Можно даже не разбивать файлы на части. Сразу между собой их сравнивать по тому же алгоритму, что и мелкие части.
Но возникает вопрос - **как правильно будет это организовать**, чтобы избежать переполнение памяти (в какой момент открывать\закрывать потоки чтения\записи файла и т.д.)?

Comment: *как правильно будет это организовать* Правильно - это когда работой с данными занимается сервер баз данных, а не скриптовый язык программирования. Так что загружаете файл на сервер во временную таблицу (20 мегабайт влетят за секунды), индексируете (ну... минута-две, вряд ли больше при таких данных), а затем одним запросом обновляетесь. А PHP, так уж и быть, пусть этим процессом рулит (хотя, если это регулярно-ежечасная задача, лучше отдайте её в Event Scheduler - MySQL и с этим справится лучше внешней программы).

Comment: Создайте индексы для таблицы, и тогда даже в PHP не будет проблем с обновлением и вставкой данных, так как основная нагрузка у вас будет поиск по этому индексу и переиндексация, а не работа PHP скрипта.